# API design for non-CRUD queries

Tags: database, api

we are considering creating an API app that our internal apps and customers can use. This seems simple for CRUD API queries, but we are having problems with more complex queries.

For example, suppose an internal app wants to know "for each company, count number of users and number of dashboards, and return the results", how would that be exposed as part of the API?

I would imagine performance becomes an issue if we issue one query for list of all companies, then fire two queries per company to count users and dashboards.

Also, how do we deal with issues where we are currently hardcoding SQLs for optimization?

Any recommended readings are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generate crud stored procedures for all database tables including selects by all foreign keys and then generate domain objects for all database tables. To me, object mapping feels more scalable to work with.

If there is a particular view of data that will cause problems or does not fit the model. I would extend an existing domain object with the extended data. For example:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID{get;set;}
}

public class CustomerListingView:Customer
{
    public int NumberOfOrders{get;set;}
    public int NumberOfSomethingElse{get;set;}
}
```

This will at least allow you to cast your custom view data to controller functions requiring the super type.

Comment: Hmmm I wouldn't do stored procedures, but the resource extension model is definitely something I should explore.